# Azure Blob Storage URL : WASB:// vs HTTP://

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I see that there are different kinds of URLS to access a blob storage like shown below:

```
wasb://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net

https://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net
```

What is the difference?
what could be the reason for difference?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From what I understand, `wasb://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net` is used to access blob storage through `HDInsight` (ref: [`http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/`](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/)) where as `https://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net` is used to access blobs through clients supporting `HTTP` protocol (web browsers etc.).

Comment: yes. wasb is the driver which implements Hadoop File System APIs, aka HDFS. Now, however you can use the new driver with ADLS Gen 2 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/data-lake-storage/

Answer (score 8):

Just to refine the previous answer a bit: wasb is the hdfs compatible API on top of Azure blob storage. So, using it you can access blobs from any hdfs client, be it part of HDInsight, a self installed IaaS hadoop cluster etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is another scheme: wasb**s** which enables secured transfers with hadoop clients.
If you always want secured transfers with your storage account you can enable secured transfers configuration through Azure portal.
[image]