# Https not supported between Usql and Blob Storage, although it seems to be?

Tags: https, azure-blob-storage, u-sql

I'm finding this works:

```
@searchlog = 
    EXTRACT UserId          int, 
            Start           DateTime, 
            Region          string, 
            Query           string, 
            Duration        int, 
            Urls            string, 
            ClickedUrls     string

    FROM @"wasb://test@strwasbsak.blob.core.windows.net/SearchLog.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();


OUTPUT @searchlog 
    TO @"/Samples/Output/SearchLog_output.tsv"
    USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

But changing the line to:

FROM @"wasb**s**://test@strwasbsak.blob.core.windows.net/SearchLog.tsv"

To ensure https, it does not.

With the error:

E_STORE_USER_FILENOTFOUND: File not found or access denied: URL is not a valid Cosmos path: wasbs://test@strwasbsak.blob.core.windows.net/SearchLog.tsv
 Parameter name: uri.

However, if I enable "Secure Transfer Required".

[image: Secure Transfer Required on]

It still works!

Which suggests to me that it's using wasbs in the background anyway?

Whereas this (albeit old) article suggests otherwise when using hadoop more generally (i.e. not u-sql): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2015/02/04/understanding-wasb-and-hadoop-storage-in-azure/

Can anyone provide an authoritative view that https is infact being used in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax: `wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`Is meant for the use of HDInsight allowing you access data stored in Azure Storage, while `https://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net` is used to access blobs through clients supporting HTTP protocol. This is the context link: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage**
There is also a similar thread on **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655092/azure-blob-storage-url-wasb-vs-http)**

**Update:**
In fact **wasb** uses **http** in the background, while wasb**s**, uses **https** in the background. This was confirmed with the internal team.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I understand that both wasb[s] and http[s] can be used and that wasbs is for HDInsight, however was I haven't found authoritative documentation for is whether wasb (without the s) is in fact securely transmitted when used by Data Lake Analytics (rather than HDInsight), although my experiments suggest it is secure.

Comment: I just escalated the issue internally, let me confirm with the HDinsight team and I'll get back to you with an update.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith I just updated the topic. Your assumption was correct, wasbs uses Https while wasb uses http :) . I updated the answer for the benefit of the community as well.

Comment: Thanks for talking to the internal teams, I gather though for U-sql / Data Lake Analytics (rather than HdInsight) this differs, as wasb appears to be https because with secure transfer enabled it still works?

Comment: indeed wasbs uses https in the background, when using the secure transfer enabled , it forces the use of https in the background, I agree that the documentation is not clear on this matter, I'll make suggestions for the responsible team to add it in the future.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify wasb (without the s) also appears to use https (with the s) in u-sql, notably different to hdinsight.